# Bootstrap5 modal not open in phpdesktopchrome

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-5, phpdesktop

Bootsrap 5 modal doesn't open in my phpdesktopchrome but on browser does

I have included all the css and js link but it still doesn't show, I have tried to check in the console on my desktop app but there is no error message, what could be the problem or how can I solve it?